# Sybase return error message

Tags: printing, sap-ase

I am using a simple script, like this one:

```
declare 
  @total int

PRINT 'TEST'
select @total = count(*) 
from TABLE BRA
where ACTIVE = 1


PRINT 'TEST 1'
if(@total > 0)
begin
    PRINT 'Variable 1 = %1', @total 
    RAISERROR 9999 'DUPLICATE'  
end
else
begin
    PRINT 'Variable 1 = %1', @total
end
```

When I run this code, the first message is printed ("TEST"), but after that nothing more is printed, I just got the following message:

```
TEST
1 row(s) affected
DECALRE executed successfully
```

Why is this happening? I am using Sybase ASE 16.0.

Comment: The more important question is what are you using as a client/front-end to submit this code to ASE? `isql` command line? some gui? `DECALRE` is a typo that wouldn't happen if you did a cut-n-paste ... so it's not apparent (to me) what **exactly** you've submitted to ASE and **exactly** what's been returned; `DECLARE executed successfully` isn't a typical message generated by ASE so can't tell if this is something your client/front-end generated, or your own comment added to the output ... ???